# Visual Studio it wants me to Modify, Repair or Uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

When it finished installing it worked OK, then I closed it, and when I re-opened , it wanted me to Modify, Repair or Uninstall (couldn't bypass it). I chose Repair, but when I close and re-open it again, it does the same and I can't seem to launch Visual Studio. The only way to use the program is through the solution I found here ( C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv (open devenv) and directly open devenv application it won't give you any error about modify repair uninstall) I should mention that I have 2 Microsoft visual studio files 12.0 and 14.0

However, is there a faster way to open it? when I click on the icon in desktop it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you'll get an answer here - there could be any number of things causing this. It may be worth trying Microsoft support to see if they suggest anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think your shortcut is corrupted.

The standard Target location of Visual studio is:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ "
with target devenv.exe.

Please check the shortcut target.
this is the correct one:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
(don't forget to include the quotation marks)

Comment: I know this is an older thread but I had the same issue after I updated to windows 10 and got some updates for visual studio.  You were right about the shortcut being corrupt somehow.  I went to the directory above (modified for 2015) and it worked like a charm